# How to change Document Library webpart's toolbar type programmatically?

Tags: development, web-part, sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365

I want to edit document library webpart to change **Toolbar Type** to **'No Toolbar'** **programmatically** using **C#**. Actually I want to **hide 'add new document' button**.

[image]

I have created a document library programmatically.

Comment: If the requirement is to simply hide the "Add new document" link, then this can also be done by using JQuery/Javascript code. I can provide the JQuery code if you need.

Comment: if you want to only hide the Add new Document link you can do it by adding a CEWB and take the class name of add new link and code in css as display:none. Also you can go to the SharePoint designer and edit the view, you will find an option toolbar there set is no toolbar it will hide the link.

Comment: @ Nadeem, @ Akarsh , I am creating document library programmatically. So I want that when it creates its toolbar type to be set as 'No'. @ Nadeem .. please provide JavaScript code here, then I will thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

@Ronak, here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Hide all Add new button links on the page. 
            $('[id^="Hero-WPQ"]').hide();
        });
</script>
```